# GraphQL mutation issue with Enum

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have object something like below:

```
type SomeEventInput {
    event: Event 
}

type Event {
    type: EventType! 
}
    
enum EventType {
    MORNING
    EVENING
    AFTERNOON
    MIDNIGHT
}

Mutation.SomeEvent(input: SomeEventInput!): Boolean!
```

What I am trying to test is something like:

```
mutation SomeEvent($input: SomeEventInput!) {
    SomeEventInput(input: {Event: {type: MORNING}})
}
```

But it is showing the following error:

```json
"message": "Variable \"$input\" is never used in operation \"SomeEvent\".",
```

Comment: It is right, you aren't using `$input` anywhere, only declaring it. Did you add that accidentally? Also seems like maybe you want `SomeEvent(input: { event: { type: MORNING } })`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an [input type](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/) to define the parameters of a mutation rather than just a `type`.

Then like @loganfsmyth points out, you want to actually use the variable you define.

Server:

```
type Event {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  type: EventType!
}

enum EventType {
  MORNING
  EVENING
  AFTERNOON
  MIDNIGHT
}

input EventInput {
  name: String!
  type: EventType!
}

type Mutation {
  CreateEvent(input: EventInput!): Event
}
```

Client:

```
mutation myMutation ($input: EventInput) {
  CreateEvent(input: $input) {
    id
    name
    type
  }
}
```

Then pass a variable into the mutation named `input` with the `name` and `type` fields. GraphQL will error if type has a value that is not included in your *enum*.